# Teradata SQL: What is Teradata's native date format? (what will have best query performance?)

Tags: sql, teradata

So I'm a data analyst and am always working with various date ranges in my data pulls (who isn't I guess).

I typically pass dates as an integer to Teradata, where 6-Jun-2019 would be passed as 1190606.  Otherwise our Teradata db supports passing date as a string as '2019-06-06'.

Recently one of our admins claimed that passing dates as an integer can degrade performance.  So I'm wondering, what's the most efficient way to pass dates to Teradata?  Which way will ensure the best query performance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1190606` is the internal storage format of a Teradata DATE, which is calculated using

```
(year - 1900) * 10000 + (month * 100) + day
```

Of course using it will not degrade performance, but it doesn't look like a proper date unless you know the formula. Try to write `1899-03-31` :-)

Don't use `'2019-06-06'`, which is simply a string and will be automatically caseted to a date based on the target column's FORMAT. Thus it might fail when that format is changed.

There's only one recommended way to write a DATE, using a Standard SQL DATE Literal which only supports a YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
DATE '2019-06-06'
```

Similar for `TIME '12:34:56.12'`  and `TIMESTAMP '2019-06-06 12:34:56.12'`

Comment: Thanks, I'll use DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD' going forward.